# How to use UITableViewDelegate.AccessoryButtonTapped (with Monotouch)

Tags: xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

I'm creating an IPad application using C#, Mono develop and Monotouch.

I've been using Monotouch.Dialog to create functionality similar to the wifi-settings on an iPhone. I'm using StyledStringElement with an accessory and am now trying to differentiate between tapping the row and tapping the DetailDisclosureButton.

I've been found out that I should override the UITableViewDelegate.AccessoryButtonTapped on the UITableView. I've tried to created a derived class from UITableViewDelegate and hook this into the Monotouch.Dialog. But this is where I got stuck. I didn't manage to replace the existing UITableViewDelegate with my extended version.

So my questions are:

1. Is this the preferred way of handling this event (to be able to differentiate between a tap on the element and a tap on the DetailDisclosureButton) ?
2. If not, any pointer on how to accomplish this ?
3. I have been searching the web for a (similar) example but have not found any yet. Any examples that you know of that could get me started ?

Thanks,

boris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
event EventHandler accessoryPushed;
public override void AccessoryButtonTapped (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
if(!accessoryPushed)
{
    accessoryPushed(this,EventArgs.Empty);
}


}
```

You will need to add this to the DailogViewController code that you are using (this will override the tapping action).  Instead of a simple function, you may want an event to be triggered, so just handle the event in your main code.  That is probably your best bet.

Once you change this line, you will have to implement new functions like AccessorySelected (just mimic the path the code follows when a row is selected except with accessory).

On the other hand, you could try a different navigation method, often disclosure buttons are annoying and you don't want to click on them except to get simple information about the button (like a help feature).

I haven't found any other examples, sorry!

Comment: So, isn't this the answer then?